How to resolve Waveshare 1.44" LCD HAT on Raspberry Pi Zero W2 with mipi-dbi-spi driver issue?
Questions

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Are the initialization commands listed for the Waveshare 1.44" LCD HAT correct?
Is there anything else missing in the setup process?

Current Issue
I'm trying to get a waveshare display connected and running on my raspberry pi zero. I take the steps listed below but after a reboot I see the following error when I run dmesg | grep mipi
[ 12.913242] panel-mipi-dbi-spi spi0.0: supply io not found, using dummy regulator
[ 12.923900] panel-mipi-dbi-spi spi0.0: config: Bad magic: 01 11 ff 78 00 02 36 00 02 3a 05 06 b2 0c 0c
[ 12.923965] panel-mipi-dbi-spi: probe of spi0.0 failed with error -22

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
My Setup

Hardware: Raspberry Pi Zero W2
Display: Waveshare 1.44" LCD HAT
OS: Raspbian Bookworm 64-bit
Driver: mipi-dbi-spi

Steps Taken

Modified /boot/config.txt:
Added the following lines:
dtoverlay=mipi-dbi-spi,spi0-0,speed=40000000
dtparam=width=128,height=128
dtparam=reset-gpio=25,dc-gpio=24


Created initialization sequence (waveshare144.txt):
command 0x11 # exit sleep mode
delay 120
command 0x36 0x00 # MADCTL: memory data access control
command 0x3A 0x05 # COLMOD: interface pixel format
command 0xB2 0x0C 0x0C 0x00 0x33 0x33 # PORCTRK: Porch setting
command 0xB7 0x35 # GCTRL: Gate Control
command 0xBB 0x1A # VCOMS: VCOM setting
command 0xC0 0x2C # LCMCTRL: LCM Control
command 0xC2 0x01 # VDVVRHEN: VDV and VRH Command Enable
command 0xC3 0x0B # VRHS: VRH Set
command 0xC4 0x20 # VDVS: VDV Set
command 0xC6 0x0F # FRCTRL2: Frame Rate control in normal mode
command 0xD0 0xA4 0xA1 # PWCTRL1: Power Control 1
command 0xE0 0xD0 0x01 0x08 0x0F 0x11 0x2A 0x36 0x55 0x44 0x3A 0x0B 0x06 0x11 0x20 # PVGAMCTRL: Positive Voltage Gamma control
command 0xE1 0xD0 0x02 0x07 0x0A 0x0B 0x18 0x34 0x43 0x4A 0x2B 0x1B 0x1C 0x22 0x1F # NVGAMCTRL: Negative Voltage Gamma control
command 0x29 # display on


Created Python script to convert initialization sequence to binary:
import struct

def create_firmware(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f_in, open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
        # Write magic number and version
        f_out.write(struct.pack('<4sI', b'MIPI', 1))

        for line in f_in:
            line = line.split('#')[0].strip()  # Remove comments
            if line.startswith('command'):
                parts = [int(x, 16) for x in line.split()[1:]]
                f_out.write(struct.pack('<B', len(parts)))
                f_out.write(struct.pack(f'<{len(parts)}B', *parts))
            elif line.startswith('delay'):
                delay = int(line.split()[1])
                f_out.write(struct.pack('<BH', 0xFF, delay))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_firmware('waveshare144.txt', 'panel.bin')

print("Firmware file created successfully.")


Generated binary firmware file:
python create_firmware.py


Copied firmware to system:
sudo cp panel.bin /lib/firmware/
sudo chmod 644 /lib/firmware/panel.bin


Rebooted the Raspberry Pi.

See current issue I am running into


Additional resources I've tried and failed:
https://github.com/notro/panel-mipi-dbi/wiki

Did you get it to work following the instructions on the waveshare site? Have you determined that device uses a MIPI DBI compatible controller
